# metamask transferred my tokens using the DEX contract?

Tags: metamask, bscscan

Today some tokens were transferred from my metamkas to another wallet, I would like to know if the type of transfer made needed my private key or could it have been through some malicious contract that I accepted on some DEX site?

this is the transaction
https://bscscan.com/tx/0x95cfbfcee44cf781d0e8c5c9dfe67620fe813a158d4cbe87fe737f92d76e185e

Esta é a carteira para qual foi meus tokens
https://bscscan.com/address/0x344f807c03213ebef62311fc21d3a29129bd2801#tokentxns

I've never offered my private key to anyone, I'm very careful about it?

Comment: It is a regular transaction from `0x93be6170c88b40f04a1043080eee0e8c50f213fc`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a normal token transfer, it wasn't a malicious contract and neither your private key was exposed